# Docker Exec command does not work properly

Tags: docker, exec

I have a script `run.sh` that I run as I initialize the container through `docker run` command. The script runs successfully. I can also get a `bash` instance (through `docker exec -i -t container-name bash`) in the container and run the script successfully (note that by default I have `su` privileges when I get the bash).

However, when I run the script from the host through `docker exec -i -t container-name /run.sh` the script runs but does not provide the outcome that it provides through the alternative approaches. I know it runs as it produces some of the expected behavior but not all of them. So my main question is what are the difference between executing a script through commandline and running the same script through `docker exec`.

Comment: Can you edit your question to show your `Dockerfile` and the contents of `run.sh`. If it is too big, can you put the part of it, which can reproduce your issue?

Comment: The content of dockerfile is irrelevant to this question. I edited the description so that my question is more clear now.

Comment: Can you try `docker exec container-name bash -c /run.sh` removing the `-i -t`? You do not need tty to run your script.